# Is it possible to prompt for a single user input to use in multiple scanf functions?

Tags: c, function, input, scanf

so I'll elaborate on the title -

Iv'e declared a few functions and  then called for them in `main`. 
All functions use `scanf`, and are supposed to do their action on an identical input.

My problem is that I'm prompted to give an input for each function (each `scanf`), but I want one single prompt. Considering all functions use an identical input, I assumed it would be straight forward.

Here's the big catch though - my input is guaranteed to be a series of letters (i.e a word - like 'hello'), and I can't use any type of strings, arrays or pointers.

I found absolutely nothing about this anywhere. Can this be done?

edit - example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^
functions - all the functions we later call for in 'main'
*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*/

//*^*^*^*^*^*^* function 1 (find sum of letter values)
int word_sum() {
    char letter = '\0';
    int sum = 0;
    while (letter != '.') {
        sum += (int)letter;
        scanf("%c", &letter);
    }
    return sum;
}

//*^*^*^*^*^*^* function 2 (number of letters in input)
int char_count() {
    char letter = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; letter != '.'; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &letter);
    }
    return i - 1;
}
//*^*^*^*^*^*^* function 3 (does something with same input)
//more functions

/*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^
main
*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*^*/
int main() {
    printf("Enter word:\n");

    printf("the sum is %d\nchar num is %d\a", word_sum(), char_count());

    return(0);
}

/* ===================
input = hi.

desired output -
--------------------------
Enter word:
hi.

the sum is 209
char num is 2
--------------------------
current output - 
--------------------------
Enter word:
hi.
hi.
the sum is 219
char num is 2
--------------------------
=====================*/
```

I use '.' at the end of the input because we are guaranteed all inputs we get will end with it.

As this shows, I'm unable to use a single prompt to initialize both functions.

Not only do I have to type the word twice, but (I'm guessing) since it reads also 'new line' or something, even the function result gets skewed.

**I know this specifically can be done with a single function and `scanf`.**
But I will have at least 5 more functions later on, and we have line limitation per function. So it would seem I'll have to confront this issue eventually one way or another.

That being said, if you can think of a different solution that maintains these functions, it could be relevant.

Thank you all so much for all your help so far!

Comment: "can't use any type of strings, arrays or pointers"-- kind of limiting your options, no?

Comment: yes, unfortunately. this is part of a homework exercise...

Comment: You are going to need to provide some code; your question is unclear. How will you use `scanf()` to read an input like `hello` without storing that input in an array? And how will `scanf()` act differently on this same input multiple times? What is the goal?

Comment: you can use `char myLetter = 'h'` for each of them with letter `e` `l` `l` `o` and then `printf("%c", myLetter)` each of them next to each other. You need to use character types. gl with the homework/ `scanf("%c", myLetter)`

Comment: What do you say like [this](https://ideone.com/ZZsdOv) ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY this seems like it might work, I tried creating a function like this but was unsuccessful. I didn't know about 'putchar', i hope i'm allowed to use it. another issue is that we can't use any condition (if, switch, etc.) but I can probably do it with a loop.

Comment: `putchar` and `puts` can be replaced with `printf`. Also `if(??){...}` can be replaced with `while(??){ ... break;}`.

Comment: @David Bowling . added code, hope this has a simple solution

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so far no luck. I added some code, if it helps

Comment: I don't think you can do this without pointers. And I don't see what value it has for the process of learning c.

Comment: What is "line limitation per function"? Are there other conditions that are not disclosed?

Comment: each user defined function (including main) cannot exceed 15 written lines. they don't count empty, comment only, and {/} only lines. function 2 for example is 6 lines, main is 4 lines.

Comment: Can I use structure or global variables?

Comment: no global variables, no static variables. im not sure what structure variables are

Comment: our biggest limitation is that we can only use the material we learned so far, but for obvious reasons I wouldn't know most of what that would exclude

Comment: You're trying to play football with one leg and no ball. Simply wait until this 'only learned so far' intro is over.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/n2xgbc)

Comment: The relevance to the function added later is unknown.

Comment: thank you all very much! As suggested I changed the method to use all functions by letter and keep the result for each one. So far seems to be the right way to go, but I still have a lot of code to write until done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is break your actual function into step functions that will perform one step of the calculation on a single character as -

```
int sum_word(char letter, int previous_sum) {
    return letter + previous_sum;
}

int count_word(char letter, int previous_count) {
    return previous_count + 1;
}
```

Now you need to read character by character and process each step as

```
void process_input(void) {
    char c;
    sum=0, count=0;
    while(scanf("%c", &c) == 1 && c != '\n'){
        sum = sum_word(c, sum);
        count = count_word(c, count);
    }
    printf ("Sum = %d, Count = %d\n", sum, count);
}
```

You can also use global/static variables for sum and count if you don't want to pass them along every time.

Now whatever other operations you want to do, just make similar one letter processing functions for them and call them where I called `sum_word` and `count_word`.

Ofcourse you cannot only support functions that can be broken down into a step function. Functions which need to look back cannot be supported.

Comment: _All functions use scanf_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that is what OP has done. Is that a necessity? If it is, we can get around it by a simple `ungetc`

Comment: There are too many ambiguous things to me ... I don't know whether `ungetc` is usable or not.  Please check with OP instead of me.

Comment: this seems likely to fit my requirements, and although I'd need to re-write most of my code this still lines up with the logic of my proposed solution. most importantly, this is within the scope of what we learned so far (we're three weeks into the course). hope it works, i'll let you know!

Comment: Ajay and @BLUEPIXY, thank you both very much, you were both very very helpful and informative!! thanks